# Constraint Layout will not scroll when put into a ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, uiscrollview

I've been trying to make my `ConstraintLayout` scroll up when the keyboard is pulled up. Ideally, I would like it to push the rest of the elements up so that you can see the entire multi-line `EditText` while making the rest of the layout scrollable. This layout is within a scene of a `Fragment`, so I'm not sure if that is preventing this from working or not.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutEditReadings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Creates margins for the sides -->
        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideLeftMargin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideRightMargin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideTopMargin"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideBottomMargin"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

        <!-- Guideline for the EditTexts -->
        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideEditStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33"/>

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideEditEnd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.90"/>

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideEditReadingTop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.47"/>

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideEditReadingBottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85"/>

        <!-- textviews -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/readingTitle"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideTopMargin"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideLeftMargin"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblAuthor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/readingAuthor"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lblTitle"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideLeftMargin"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/readingPart"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lblAuthor"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideLeftMargin"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/readingText"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lblPart"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideLeftMargin"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

        <!-- Edit Texts -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/titleHint"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideEditStart"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideEditEnd"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideTopMargin"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editAuthor"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/authorHint"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideEditStart"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideEditEnd"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editPart"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/partHint"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideEditStart"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideEditEnd"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editAuthor"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

        <!-- larger EditText for the readings -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editReading"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="8"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lblText"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideEditReadingBottom"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideLeftMargin"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideRightMargin"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/submitReading"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideBottomMargin"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideLeftMargin"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideRightMargin" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here are screenshots of what the layout looks like:

[image: Before keyboard]
[image: After keyboard]

Comment: This is working, the problem is that you have added margin to your elements. This margin prevents the elements from narrowing so as to obtain room for the rest of the elements.